# Flutter is there any possible way to make user having online status when the user open the app

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, dart

how can i create the online status bar when user online and when user offline/closed the app, how can i put something look like "Online 12 minute ago" using firebase. i dont know how it work with flutter and firebase to do that.

now it work using this code

```
 final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
    setStatus('Online')
  }

  void setStatus(String status) async {
    await _firestore.collection('users').doc(_auth.currentUser!.uid).update({
      'status': status,
    });
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      // online
      setStatus('Online');
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused ||
        state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
      // offline
      setStatus('Offline');
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can manually check if user is online after some interval and save the time on firebase. Then access the last online time on other account.

Comment: what method i should use to check it?

Comment: Answer is below

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
const oneMin = Duration(minutes:1);
Timer.periodic(oneMin, (Timer t){
    //your function to save current time in firebase
    //Can also check last seen of other users here
})
```

But when you check last seen time of other users, if lastseen is before one minute then user is offline otherwise user is online

Comment: okok, letme try to use it first, thanks for the help, so that mean i should upload a time value every time user open the app?

Comment: Not only open the app. As i showed up in the code, it will be uploaded after every minute user opens the app

Comment: ah so its upload the timestamp every 1 minute and i will receive the timestamp that i was on the same minute as in the firestore?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WidgetsBindingObserver` to manage the user's online/offline status

Add observer

```dart
class _HomeState extends State<Home> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
...

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);

  }
```

Remove observer

```dart
  @override
  void dispose() {

    WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);

    super.dispose();
  }
```

Handle the state

```dart
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);

    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {

      updateStatus(true);

    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused ||
        state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {

      updateStatus(false);

    }
  }
```

> how can I put something look like "Online 12 minutes ago" using firebase.

For that, you can store the current timestamp in the firebase when the user is offline.
And to show time/date in the ago format you can use [timeago](https://pub.dev/packages/timeago)

Comment: im trying to did this but its only setting my status into online, not going offline even i close the app

Comment: try to check my question, i already put my code that i've tried alrd

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is known as a presence system, and is quite well described in the Firebase documentation for the [offline capabilities](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities) of its Realtime Database, specifically the section on [managing presence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-presence) and the [full example of a presence app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-sample).